# How to access phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu LAMP

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, lamp

I have installed all LAMP, and phpMyAdmin too. But how do I access phpMyAdmin via my browser? Which URL do I need to open?

Comment: Check out this site it should help you http://www.blog.highub.com/linux/install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-lamp/

Comment: No. How I CAN ACCESS to the phpmyadmin index.php. I need access phpmyadmin interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should probably see these instructions

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin

but phpmyadmin must be at /usr/share/phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on ubuntu, try `which phpmyadmin` and then set your search paths accordingly.